# VCR re-recording cassette does not persist

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, vcr, rubymine-7

Thanks in advance - i'm recording a controller spec with vcr.

The problem:

The first time I run my spec, it records fine, then I delete my_spec_context_dir, re-run the spec, and no cassette is saved under the cassettes dir!

The gems:

```
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
gem 'webmock', '1.22.3', require: false
gem 'vcr'
gem 'capybara', '~> 2.4.3'
```

The spec:

```
#spec/controllers/my_spec.rb
require 'unit_spec_helper'
describe 'description' do
    it 'example_name', :vcr do
      @instance_var = table_record.attribute

      get 'controller_action'

      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
      expect(response.content_type).to eq 'image/png'
      table_record.delete
    end
  end
```

What i've tried:

So I look at my configs to make sure vcr should be recording each time its run:

```
#spec/unit_spec_helper.rb
require 'vcr'
if Rails.env.test?
  VCR.configure do |c|
    c.ignore_localhost = false
    c.hook_into :webmock
    c.cassette_library_dir = "spec/support/cassettes"
    c.configure_rspec_metadata!
    c.allow_http_connections_when_no_cassette = true
    c.default_cassette_options = {
        allow_playback_repeats: true,
        serialize_with: :json,
        record: :all,
        match_requests_on: [:method, :uri, :headers]
    }
    c.debug_logger = File.open(Rails.root.join('log/vcr.log'), 'w')
  end
end
```

`allow_playback_repeats: true, record: :all` - yep, I think thats what I want

Checking the vcr.log, I see that the cassette was recorded:

`[Cassette: 'MyController/description/example_name'] Initialized with options: {:record=>:new_episodes, :match_requests_on=>[:method, :uri, :headers], :allow_unused_http_interactions=>true, :serialize_with=>:json, :persist_with=>:file_system, :allow_playback_repeats=>true}`

`spec/support/cassettes` dir is still empty, so i'm clearing the cache before the test... `Rails.cache.clear` and re-running.

Refreshing the `spec/support/cassettes` directory, I see its still empty. What do you suppose is keeping the .yml from saving?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be an issue with RubyMine7 - after a few restarts, it works.